# Determinant of PSD matrices

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, determinant

I'm trying to show that the determinant of X is the product of the eigenvalues. How would I do this? I know I have to do eigenvalue decomposition but I'm not sure how to proceed.

Comment: One of the simplest way is to use the Schur decomposition. BTW it does not matter whether the matrix $X$ is PSD or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Schur decomposition is a sort of eigenvalue decomposition as well. Each $X\in\mathbb{C}^{n\times n}$ can be written as $X=QTQ^*$, where $Q$ is unitary and $T=(t_{ij})$ upper triangular with the eigenvalues of $X$ on the diagonal. Then $$\det{X}=\det{Q}\det{T}\det{Q^*}=\det{Q}\;\overline{\det{Q}}\;\det{T}=|\det{Q}|\det{T}.$$ The absolute value of the determinant of any unitary matrix is equal to one. The determinant of a triangular matrix is given by the product of its diagonal elements. Hence
$$
\det{X}=\det{T}=\prod_{i=1}^n t_{ii}=\prod_{i=1}^n\lambda_i(X).
$$

For Hermitian (or normal) matrices, replace "upper triangular" with "diagonal". Result is the same.